# manipulate and sort text file

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, text

I am working on a project where I have been given a `text file` and I have to add up the points for each team and printout the top 5 teams.

The text file looks like this:

```
FRAMae Berenice MEITE         455.455<br>
CHNKexin ZHANG                454.584<br>
UKRNatalia POPOVA             453.443<br>
GERNathalie WEINZIERL         452.162<br>
RUSEvgeny PLYUSHCHENKO        191.399<br>
CANPatrick CHAN               189.718<br>
CHNHan YAN                    185.527<br>
CHNCheng & Hao                271.018<br>
ITAStefania & Ondrej          270.317<br>
USAMarissa & Simon            264.256<br>
GERMaylin & Daniel            260.825<br>
FRAFlorent AMODIO             179.936<br>
GERPeter LIEBERS              179.615<br>
JPNYuzuru HANYU               197.9810<br>
USAJeremy ABBOTT              165.654<br>
UKRYakov GODOROZHA            160.513<br>
GBRMatthew PARR               157.402<br>
ITAPaul Bonifacio PARKINSON   153.941<br>
RUSTatiana & Maxim            283.7910<br>
CANMeagan & Eric              273.109<br>
FRAVanessa & Morgan           257.454<br>
JPNNarumi & Ryuichi           246.563<br>
JPNCathy & Chris              352.003<br>
UKRSiobhan & Dmitri           349.192<br>
CHNXintong &Xun               347.881<br>
RUSYulia LIPNITSKAYA          472.9010<br>
ITACarolina KOSTNER           470.849<br>
JPNMao ASADA                  464.078<br>
UKRJulia & Yuri               246.342<br>
GBRStacey & David             244.701<br>
USAMeryl &Charlie             375.9810<br>
CANTessa & Scott              372.989<br>
RUSEkaterina & Dmitri         370.278<br>
FRANathalie & Fabian          369.157<br>
ITAAnna & Luca                364.926<br>
GERNelli & Alexander          358.045<br>
GBRPenny & Nicholas           352.934<br>
USAAshley WAGNER              463.107<br>
CANKaetlyn OSMOND             462.546<br>
GBRJenna MCCORKELL            450.091<br>
```

The first three letters represent the team. 
the rest of the text is the the competitors name.
The last digit is the score the competitor recived.

Code so far:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class project2 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] array = new String[41];
    String[] info = new String[41];
    String[] stats = new String[41];
    String[] team = new String[41];

    //.txt file location

    FileInput fileIn = new FileInput();
    fileIn.openFile("C:\\Users\\O\\Desktop\\turn in\\team.txt");

    // txt file to array
    int i = 0;
    String line = fileIn.readLine();
    array[i] = line;
    i++;
    while (line != null) {

      line = fileIn.readLine();
      array[i] = line;
      i++;
    }

    //Splitting up Info/team/score into seprate arrays

    for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++) {
      team[j] = array[j].substring(0, 3).trim();
      info[j] = array[j].substring(3, 30).trim();
      stats[j] = array[j].substring(36).trim();
    }


    // Random stuff i have been trying  
    System.out.println(team[1]);
    System.out.println(info[1]);
    System.out.println(stats[1]);
    MyObject ob = new MyObject();
    ob.setText(info[0]);
    ob.setNumber(7, 23);
    ob.setNumber(3, 456);
    System.out.println("Text is " + ob.getText() + " and number 3 is " + ob.getNumber(7));
  }
}
```

I'm pretty much stuck at this point because I am not sure how to add each teams score together.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework... First of all you need to examine how you are parsing the strings in the file.

You're saying: the first 3 characters are the country, which looks correct, but then you set the info to the 4th through the 30th characters, which isn't correct. You need to dynamically figure out where that ends and the score begins. There is a space between the "info" and the "stats," knowing that you could use String's indexOf function. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int))

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Maps.

A map is a collection that allows you to get data associated with a key in a very short time.
You can create a Map where the key is a country name, with value being the total points.

example:

```
Map<String,Integer> totalScore = new HashMap<>();

if (totalScore.containsKey("COUNTRYNAME"))
    totalScore.put("COUNTRYNAME", totalScore.get("COUNTRYNAME") + playerScore)
else
    totalScore.put("COUNTRYNAME",0)
```

This will add to the country score if the score exists, otherwise it will create a new totalScore for a country initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but should give you some ideas:

```
public static void main(String... args)
        throws Exception {

    class Structure implements Comparable<Structure> {
        private String team;

        private String name;

        private Double score;

        public Structure(String team, String name, Double score) {
            this.team = team;
            this.name = name;
            this.score = score;
        }

        public String getTeam() {
            return team;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Double getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Structure o) {
            return this.score.compareTo(o.score);
        }
    }


    File file = new File("path to your file");
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file.toURI()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+))");

    List<Structure> structures = new ArrayList<Structure>();
    for (String line : lines) {

        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        while (m.find()) {
            String number = m.group(1);
            String text = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(number) - 1);
            double d = Double.parseDouble(number);

            String team = text.substring(0, 3);
            String name = text.substring(3, text.length());

            structures.add(new Structure(team, name, d));
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(structures);
    List<Structure> topFive = structures.subList(0, 5);

    for (Structure structure : topFive) {
        System.out.println("Team: " + structure.getTeam());
        System.out.println("Name: " + structure.getName());
        System.out.println("Score: " + structure.getScore());
    }
}
```

Just remove `<br>` from your file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Loading file into memory

Your string splitting logic looks fine.
Create a class like PlayerData. Create one instance of that class for each row and set all the three fields into that using setters.
Keep adding the PlayerData objects into an array list.

2. Accumulating

Loop through the arraylist and accumulate the team scores into a hashmap. Create a Map to accumulate the team scores by mapping teamCode to totalScore.

Always store row data in a custom object for each row. String[] for each column is not a good way of holding data in general.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in [File Utils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines(java.io.File)). After that you can extract the content from last space character using [String Utils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#line.1153) e removing the <br> using it as a key for a TreeMap. Than you can have your itens ordered.

```
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(yourFile);
Map<String, String> ordered = new TreeMap<>();

for (String s : lines) {
  String[] split = s.split(" ");
  String name = split[0].trim();
  String rate = splt[1].trim().substring(0, key.length - 4);
  ordered.put(rate, name);
}

Collection<String> rates = ordered.values(); //names ordered by rate
```

Of course that you need to adjust the snippet.